# How to throw definite quantity of an item in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Me and friends play on WiFi LAN , but we are having hard time in giving items to each other.
What happens is when I want to give, let's say 20 Birch Blocks to one of my friend I have to long press the icon of it at bottom items menu but when the process is done (ie the green bar fills upto top) it transfers all the blocks not just 20 / quantity I want. 
Can we throw items individual or in definite quantity ? If yes how so?

We are using 1.0.0.16 version , if someone is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either split it up in a chest beforehand, or use the new "Classic" interface (I believe it is in the video area of the settings), to split it up in your inventory (hold and drag to split, tap on one stack then another to merge, you'll eventually be able to separate 20 from a stack). Then, you can either put it in your hotbar and hold on it, or you can tap on it in your inventory and then tap out of the inventory to drop it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just hold down for about a second and not let the green bar fill all of the way up, and it may drop one or a few.

Also, I'm not sure if this can work on mobile but you may be able to drag the amount of blocks you want out of your inventory into the empty gaps round the side and it should drop them onto the floor. However, I am not sure if this works on mobile, but I know it works on PC, so tell me if it works or not!

Hope this helps!
Owen

Comment: Sorry to say it does not work , I have already tried it it just abruptly stops the process of throwing. Also I know I can but the whole process is time consuming and quite hard to pull out in night.

Comment: I don't know of another way to do this then, as I imagine most things are time consuming when playing on a smaller screen (you won't be able to have as any shortcuts)

Comment: I now noticed that I can't drag and simply drop the blocks of quantity I wanted in PE. I need to build a chest then put some quantity there till I have amount or put all blocks and then add that quantity to my slots. Well this consumes a lot time. It happens because same types of blocks sums up like if I have 52 blocks in inventory and 1 in chest , then after transferring it will 53 blocks not 52 and 1 separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a hopper into a hopper.Put the items that you want to split into one of the hoppers.Look into the hopper on the other side.You’l see 1 of the item you put in the first hopper.Take it out and another one will appear.Keep doing this until you have the exact amount you want.